# Always import 3 different random samples in a (set)

Tags: python

So in my csv file I'm importing there is 100 names, some of which are the same name. When I import 3 random samples and any are 2 duplicates and 1 different name it will only print the 2 names; but what I'm wanting to do is instead always print 3 so if any duplicates are picked then it will find another and then print the output. So far I have it like this...

```
    Names1 = random.sample (Names, 3)
    if Names1==(Names, 2):
        print(Names, 1)
    list(set(Names1))
    for i in set(Names1):
        print(i)
```

So the problem is: `if Names1==(Names, 2): // print(Names, 1)`
I know this code is wrong but I can't think of a way to do it. Anybody know a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Please provide some sample input and expected output.

Comment: Sample  the `set`: `random.sample(set(Names), 3)`

Comment: Just remove the duplicate names, and pick from the *set of unique names*.

Comment: @DeepSpace yeah that is exctly what i needed, worked perfectly thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `set` of names first, then just sample:

```
names_set = set(Names)  # only unique values in a set
Names1 = random.sample(names_set, 3)
```

So, you'll newer get  a duplicated names, because `set` contains unique values.